# Application life cycle for Custom PIN Android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I'm using a child lock in my app. when the app resumes I could call the password activity to confirm the PIN. How I can implement the Application life cycle in android app.

Thank you.

Comment: you can try with logger and then check the life cycle call..

Comment: You can show password dialog on onResume() of every activity. for short code you can extend your all activities by a base class. and ask password on OnResume() of base class.

Comment: How is that possible, When a user launches the app, Then it will always irritate him.Because the onResume() always called while creating an activity also.

Comment: you could try to add a flag that's false by default and only becomes true when `onPause()` is called then in `onResume()` check that flag and if its true ask for a PIN that way when the activity is first created it won't ask, if that's what you need(`onPause()` should only be called when the activity isn't fully visible, you could also try to use `onStop()` and `onStart()` as `onStop()` will be called when the activity goes to foreground).

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fixed my problem.

I just used a global `Activty` and checked whether `activity` is running or not.

```
class CryptActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String TAG = "HII";
public boolean wasPaused = false;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Log.e(TAG, "onResume: RESUME " + wasPaused);

    if (wasPaused) {
        showLockScreen();
        wasPaused = false;
    }

}

private void showLockScreen() {

    SessionManager session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    if (session.getPin() != -1)
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PasswordActivity.class));

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (isApplicationInBackground()) {
        wasPaused = true;
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "onPause: PAUSE" + wasPaused);
}

private boolean isApplicationInBackground() {
    final ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    assert manager != null;
    final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        final ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        return !topActivity.getPackageName().equals(getPackageName());
    }
    return false;
}
```

}